# Get named MAPI Property from MailItem in C#

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, mapi, outlook-2010, mailitem

I'm developing an Outlook 2010 custom plugin in C#. This is my first time using C# (I'm a java guy normally).

There is a named (custom) MAPI property on a message that I would like to access and am having trouble doing so. My understanding is that in Outlook 2007 the PropertyAccessor object was introduced which allows easy access to named MAPI properties. I followed the instructions from the following documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff868915.aspx

I can see the named MAPI property I want to access on the message using Outlook Spy. From Outlook Spy I can get the following information about the property:

```
GUID:    {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
Tag num: 0x80BE0102
ID:      PR.AFU.MESSAGE.RETRIEVE.INFO
Type:    PT_BINARY
```

So I tried the following code (Object mail is a valid instance of MailItem):

```
mail.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/80BE0102");
```

This produces the following exception:

```
The property "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/80BE0102" is unknown or cannot be found
```

So I'm wondering how to actually get this property? Am I forming the namespace reference incorrectly? Or do I need to use an approach as outlined in this example:

http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=1112

My understanding was that this was only necessary for pre 2007 versions of Outlook. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) will give you the DASL property name in the DASL edit box in the IMessage window (select a message with the property set, click IMessage button, select the property, look at the DASL edit box)

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try

```
mail.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x80BE0102");
```

?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet because my understanding is that method only works for exchange properties that have a tag number < 0x80000000. I'll try it though and report back if it is successful.

Comment: That approach of using the proptag reference didn't work either.

Comment: Using the String schema worked:

    mail.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/PR.AFU.MESSAGE.RETRIEVE.INFO");

Comment: good to know... I only read that a module from IBM for exchange had last october the same issue with the same property... they announced a bugfix but didn't write how it was fixed...

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft's MFCMapi](http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/) is also a great tool to locate the DASL and view all MAPI properties.