# C# Problems getting a specific named MAPI property from a .msg

Tags: c#, outlook, mapi

I'm having a similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862325/get-named-mapi-property-from-mailitem-in-c-sharp) in getting a pair of "custom" MAPI properties from a MailItem in a C# console app, but with the extra twist that it works locally but not on the server.

The two properties are PR_SERVERID and PR_MSGID and both are available on the mailitems when inspected via MFCMAPI, I'm accessing them as follows:

```
MessageDetails.PR_SERVERID = Message.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/PR_SERVERID").ToString();

MessageDetails.PR_MSG_ID = Message.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/PR_MSGID").ToString();
```

Where Message is of type `Outlook.MailItem`. When I run this locally (from built exe or in debug) it works but on a separate server the exact same message fails with:

```
15:17:26 Error getting getting MAPI properties from the stub: 
System.ApplicationException: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004010F): 
The property "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/PR_SERVERID" is unknown or cannot be found.
```

Before this, I am successfully retrieving two "standard" MAPI properties (PR_CREATOR_NAME and PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID) from the same item so the MailItem is accessible.

The DASL for the properties shown in MFCMAPI is identical between the two servers and my local machine and both are running Outlook 2010 and accessing the mailItem by invoking an Outlook session.

The only thing I could think of was that Outlook itself is unable to recognise the custom properties without some configuration that's missing on the remote server(s), does Outlook have to have a property configured at the namespace level for it to be recognised even if identified by a DASL?

Edit: Additional information on the mail items:
The mails are "stubs" downloaded from an archive system, the two attributes then provide the identifier for the "full" message content. I'm downloading the stub from the remote server, saving it locally and then accessing each stub in the set using:

```
Outlook.NameSpace NS = _outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Object item = _outlookApplication.Session.OpenSharedItem(MessageDetails.FilePath)
Outlook.MailItem Message = (Outlook.MailItem)item;
```

And attempting to add the two properties to the `MessageDetails` object by getting the properties from `Message`.

**Edit 2:**

<strike>I've noticed that when retrieving the properties on  a "fresh" host, I get a security prompt for "a program is trying to access e-mail address information stored in Outlook" when I access the custom properties but *not* when I access the subjectline/sender etc. from the standard properties. The seems to indicate that there is something about these custom properties that is "different" when accessed via COM interop using outlook.</strike> Nevermind, this is simply default protection on calling PropertyAccessor.GetProperty.

**Answer:**
Dmitry is spot on and I have marked his response as the answer, the properties were not accessible because they had never been created on the store. With user machines these have been created because at some point we "archived" mails into the remote store and set the custom properties on the stubs left in our mail boxes. On the servers this had never been done so I added an option for a "first run" that creates a dummy object, sets two empty custom properties on it, saves it then deletes it. Subsequent runs are then able to access the properties using PropertyAccessor.GetProperty.

Comment: How are you opening the MSG file? Do you see these properties for that particular MSG file (click OpenIMsgOnIStg in OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/)

Or is it a message in one of Outlook folders?

Comment: The message is downloaded from a remote server and saved locally, it's then opened using
    Outlook.NameSpace NS = _outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Object item = _outlookApplication.Session.OpenSharedItem(MessageDetails.FilePath);

The two properties show on the file when opened via outlook spy, though the DASL is shown with the type appended e.g. http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/PR_SERVERID/0x00000003 running the same code with the type appended gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook Object Model always assumes `PT_UNICODE` / `PT_STRING8` type for the properties in the "string" namespace. The type in your case is `PT_LONG` (`0x0003`).

As a test, can you install [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) (I am its author) and try the following script from [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am also its author - click Script, paste the script, click Run)

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set Msg = Session.GetMessageFromMsgFile("c:\temp\yourmsg.msg")
  MsgBox Msg.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/PR_SERVERID/0x00000003")
```

**UPDATE**
Try the following script in OutlookSpy on a machine where your code fails. When the IMessage window pops up, do you see the named properties?

```
set msg = Application.Session.OpenSharedItem("c:\temp\yourmsg.msg")
BrowseObject(msg.MAPIOBJECT)
```

Comment: Running the script for the two properties shows the values in the popup,I also tried using the attribute "PR_MSGID2" which is the same value but stored as a string rather than PT_LONG, this works via Outlookspy/redemption on the remote server but it still fails when run from the console app.

Comment: "fails when run from the console app" - does that code use Redemption like the sample script above or the Outlook Object Model?

Comment: No I'm using the COM interop method so invoking an Outlook session then using Outlook.MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty([DASL]); to return the values.

Comment: I am confused - so it works with Outlook Object Model on one machine, but not on another for the same MSG file?

Comment: Exactly. I tested on a colleagues machine and it also worked for him, but on any of the separate servers (Server 2008, same version of Outlook) it fails with the "property is unknown" error. All I can think is that there is something in Outlook 2010 that prevents reading custom properties that has been disabled as part of our local builds but not on the servers.

Comment: Does Redemption code above work in all cases? It might due to a fact that Outlook creates a temporary copy of the message in one of Outlook folders and copies the MSG file data there. If that particular named property mapping was never created in the primary store, the named property will not be copied.

Comment: Try the test script from the updated answer above. Do you see the properties?

Comment: Just checked this, the properties are visible on my local machine but **not** in Outlook on the server.

Comment: Makes perfect sense - I know Exchange and Outlook did that for the X-header properties in MIME messages: unless the property was already mapped in that store, it will not be propagated to a named MAPI property to avoid a DOS attack: since there can be a limited number of named properties (0xFFFF per mailbox) - a malicious email can exhaust the supply of named properties in a store.  Note that GetMessageFromMsgFile in Redemption opens the MSG file directly without creating a copy in the default store, hence nothing is copied and it can see all the properties present.

Comment: Dmitry you're a genius. I'd seen some references to the DOS protection from adding excessive properties to a mail but didn't realise it would kick in when opening a local file. I've done a quick test and it looks like it's possible to add these properties manually to the store (there's probably a better way to do it in the application itself but doing it manually works for now) and they then get recognised. I'll confirm this and mark this as the answer if it all works!

Comment: Yep, if you do PropertyAccessor.SetProperty on any object in that store to set the properties, MSG file properties should come through.

Answer (score -1):

I would guess that the interface defined by {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} is not installed on the server. Search for it (e.g. using Regedit) on your machine where it works, and note what dll it is associated with (this will be in the InprocServer32 sub key as the default property. Then do the same on the server: it will probably not find the CLSID at all.

If this is the case, then you need to install the missing dll - and all its dependencies which means the package it was wrapped up in.

Comment: This is not an interface. This is namespace guid used by Extended MAPI.

Comment: {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} is the namespace GUID for custom properties so isn't registered by itself. There's some information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863459%28v=office.14%29.aspx) that mentions that a filter query must reference the property type if not set on the folder being filtered, however I'm not filtering a folder, I'm accessing a single mail directly