# PRSMTPADDRESS Url is temporarily unavailable

Tags: outlook, vsto

I am trying to access the URL: http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E and I am getting  a result as follows:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I use this URL to get SMTP address of the Exchange agent.

My code is as follows

string PR_SMTP_ADDRESS = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E";

```
PropertyAccessor pa = sender.PropertyAccessor;
                    email = pa.GetProperty(
                        PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) as string;
                    COMHelper.ReleaseComObject(ref pa);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a URL, it is a DASL property name. Much like a namespace in HTML/XML/etc.

Answer (score 0):

As Dmitry mentioned, this is a Namespace. You can refer to the following link to know more information.

[Referencing Properties by Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/navigation/referencing-properties-by-namespace)

[Get named MAPI Property from MailItem in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862325/get-named-mapi-property-from-mailitem-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

See How to: [Get the SMTP Address of the Sender of a Mail Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184624(v=office.15).aspx).

Also you may find the HowTo: [Convert Exchange-based email address into SMTP email address article helpful.](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/05/08/outlook-exchange-email-address-smtp/)